# Roll-Up Summary field filter limited in number of added criteria

Tags: formula-field, master-detail, roll-up-summary

I have two objects object A ( Master ) and object B ( Detail).I am trying to create a rollup summary field on master A object of Select Roll-Up Type `Count`.
 However, when I try to add a criteria to the filter I see a limited number of criteria which can be added to the filter.
 5 to be exact. Is there any possible workaround to help me add a 6th criteria to the rollup summary field?
 If not could you please give an example of a formula field which can possibly replace my rollup summary field?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do rollup summary on Formula fields (see this [Idea and vote it up](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrUAAA0)) but you have two alternatives

**Option 1** - Create a checkbox field on `Object B` that is populated by WFR, Process Builder, or Lightning Flow.

Call the field `Is_Qualified_For_RSF___c`

Use the aforementioned automation to set to true if all 6 conditions are true

Change your RSF to just use this new checkbox field

**Option2** - Use the [DLRS package](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free). It will rollup any number of criteria on Object B.

DLRS is point and click configuration but under the hood, it reacts as a trigger on CRUD to object B